# "the" with knowledge

Tags: definite-article

Can I use article “the” with the word “knowledge” as shown in following 2 cases:

1. XX, (20005) use **the knowledge** about the human body **for the segmenting** of anatomical structures from medical image.
2. The aim is to solve these tasks by using **the knowledge** about the information of anatomical structures into the segmentation process.

Comment: aki, I don't see any problem to use "the" before "knowledge"; especially when it is mandatory, as is in your two examples.

Comment: @Carlo_R well, if I rewrite these without using "the", is if not reflect correct meaning.

Comment: aki, IMO it is no matter of "correct meaning", but of grammar. I can say "I have not sufficient knowledge to tell you if the article is mandatory," and, you can observe that I don't have used "the". Why? Because there knowledge is used in the so-called "mass" form, which is not the case in your examples.

Comment: @Carlo_R. But you can say "I don't have the knowledge to tell you if the article is mandatory."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are talking of a specific knowledge, the article is correct. If you were talking of knowledge in abstract, then you would not use the article, as in "a thirst for knowledge" or "the transmission of knowledge."